# Filter Pagination results on Contained column

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have two tables in my database Members and Memberitems. I created two models for it. one is, Member and another is Memberitem

Member model has hasMany relation to Memberitem, and Memberitem model has belongsTo relations with my Member model.

Memberitem entries has specific categorization based on color, like, Red, Pink, Green, etc.
Now I want to select all the members who has atleast one Pink color memberitem using pagination.

Currently I am using:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 5,
    'contain' => array(
        'Memberitem' => array(
            'conditions' => array('Memberitem.color' => 'Pink')
        )
    )
);
```

But its showing all the Members.

output is this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Member] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [first_name] => fh
                [last_name] => g
            )

        [Memberitem] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => item2
                        [color]=> Pink
                    )
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Member] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [first_name] => ad
                [last_name] => vd
            )

        [Memberitem] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Member] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [first_name] => ae
                [last_name] => sdi
            )

        [Memberitem] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [name] => item1
                        [color]=> Pink
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Its showing this result. Member of empty memberitem is still there. I want only 1st and 3 record in result.

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic :-) It takes a while to get it though.

The Cake manual has an excellent peace on this. You should read: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations

So if you want only Members with certain MemberItems, you should query on the MemberItems and contain the Member Model. You can actually do this from Member Model:

```
$this->Member->Memberitem->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => 'Memberitem.color = "Pink"',
    'contain' => 'Member',
));
```

or maybe a bit more catered to you app:

```
$this->paginate['Memberitem'] = array(
    'contain' => array('Member'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Memberitem.color' => 'Pink',
    ),
);
$items = $this->paginate('Memberitem');
```

Hope that helps!